# “Setting up iCloud Drive” just spins in the Finder Window?

Tags: macos, icloud, finder

It freaks me out, iDrive doesn't want to work (to be specific: it's since 4 days like this). Here is a photo, click me! - https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jO7s.png

I already contacted the apple support, they have no damn clue and forwarded it to the apple devs, this may take weeks. I don't have that time :(

We already tried several things (with the support). rebooting, safemode, disconnecting apple ID, reinstalling big sur, and so on. Nothing works, it's really a problem on apple's side. I also read a thread on some apple board that is just a couple of months old, where a guy had the same problem, and the Apple Devs had to fix it, he had a Mac Mini M1. I have a MBP Mid 2015.

iCloud Drive does work on the web and on my iPhone, but not with my Mac(book pro), we tried it with different users: no solution.

I am really frustrated, I appreciate every help!

Comment: Any solution? I have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

There is every chance that this is a coincidence but I'm not inclined to test it again to find out.

Mine was stuck on "setting up iCloud drive" until I **unchecked** the "Optimise Mac Storage" box in iCloud preferences, then things kicked in.

YMMV. Would appreciate knowing if this helped anybody.

[image: Optimise Mac storage]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to enable syncing for the drive first, which is kind of weird. I waited for a long time, still spinning.

Then checking the option in **System Preferences** > **Internet Accounts** > **iCloud** called "Desktop & Documents Folders" helped! It was unchecked before.

[image: Screenshot of the Internet Accounts preferences pane showing 'Apps that store documents and data in iCloud will appear here:']

Comment: Note that primary effect of this setting replicates essentially all of one's personal files, which can easily exceed the storage capacity of the iCloud account.